# Counting distinct values in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like the one below.  I'm trying to group and count them, but haven't been able to get it to work.

The original $result array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [sku] => Array
        (
            [0] => 344
            [1] => 344
            [2] => 164
        )

    [cpk] => Array
        (
            [0] => d456
            [1] => d456
        )
)
```

I'm trying to take this and create a new array:

```
$item[sku][344] = 2;
$item[sku][164] = 1;
$item[cpk][d456] = 1;
```

I've gone through various iterations of in_array statements inside for loops, but still haven't been able to get it working.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I removed the "potential solution" tags that you added to this question to prevent [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use `in_array()` personally here.

This just loops through creating the array as it goes.

It [seems to work](http://codepad.org/7WAXFZLX) without needing to first set the index as 0.

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($result as $key => $group) {   
    foreach($group as $member) {
        $newArray[$key][$member]++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: @Ralph Don't know. I guess if I do arithmetic (`++`) on it, it is case to an integer of `0`.